# JavaScript hiding and showing form elements

Tags: javascript, forms, element

```
Options:    
<select id="selectOption" name="Option">

<option value="">Choose Option</option>

<option value="option1">1</option>

<option value="option2">2</option>

</select>

<div id="option1" class="">

//form element here//

</div>

<div id="option2" class="">

//form element here//

</div>
```

My question is, using JavaScript, how do make it so that at the start you don't see the 2 divs at the bottom? When you choose option 1, it should only show the first div and if you choose option2 it shows the second div.

Comment: check the display property of elements in html.. display='none' will hide them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
<select id="selectOption" name="Option" onchange="optionSelect()">

<option value="">Choose Option</option>

<option value="option1">1</option>

<option value="option2">2</option>

</select>

<div id="option1" style="display:none">
DIV1
//form element here//

</div>

<div id="option2" style="display:none">
DIV2
//form element here//

</div>
```

Then in script:

```
function optionSelect(){
    var e = document.getElementById("selectOption");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById(strUser).style.display = "block";
}
```

What i'm doing is listening for option change, whenever option is changing im getting its value and making the div with that option value visible `display='block'`

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/8fffb8bw/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can make both the `div`s hidden by default and trigger an `onchange` on the select.

In the javascript function, check the value and hide/show the corresponding `div`.

`<select id="selectOption" name="Option" onchange='checkOption()'>`

Javascript:

```
function checkOption() {
   document.getElementsByTagName('div').style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById(document.getElementById('selectOption').value).style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this

```
<select id="selectOption" name="Option" onChange="showDiv(this)">
   <option value="">Choose Option</option>
   <option value="option1">1</option>
   <option value="option2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="option1" class="" style="display:none;">
//form element here option 1//
</div>

<div id="option2" class="" style="display:none;">
//form element here option 2//
</div>

<script>
function showDiv(selectObj){
    var valueSelected= selectObj.value;

    // hide all div again
    document.getElementById('option1').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('option2').style.display = "none";

    // show the selected
    document.getElementById(valueSelected).style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

The `showDiv`function is called everytime you are selecting an option from the select.

In the function, it gets the value, since the value is the id of the div you can use it as the identifier.

First hide both div then display the selected, doing it  when user selects the very first it will hide both.

Answer (score 0):

algorithm to do what you've asked:

1. Initially hide all the divs
2. set the id's of div's equal to select option tag values
3. use onchange function of select tag and call a function
4. in that function hide all other divs and show corresponding div only.

Here is he jsbin.
http://jsbin.com/pewihumokunu/1/edit